# Page Breaks in Two-Column, Multi-Page Table

Tags: tables, longtable, two-column, supertabular, xtab

I'm currently using `xtab` to create long tables that span two columns, and multiple pages. What I'd like to do is have a finer degree of control over when the table is broken on a page / column boundary. I'm using `\twocolumn` for get the two columns.

Based on my research, `supertabular` doesn't seem to respect / pay attention to `\newpage` or `\pagebreak` — but `longtable` does. However, `longtable` doesn't support multiple columns. I understand `xtab` is something of an improved version of `supertabular`, but it also doesn't seem to respect `\pagebreak` or `\newpage`. The example below spans two pages, with two columns, with two ideal break points indicated. These tables are cue sheets for long bicycling routes, and I'd prefer column / page breaks to occur at sane stopping points, like pit stops, water breaks, etc. Is there any simple way to go about this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.25in,right=0.25in,top=0.25in,bottom=0.25in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xtab}

\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\tabletail{\hline}
\tablelasttail{\hline}
\begin{xtabular}{|p{0.25in}|p{0.35in}|p{2.25in}|l|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor[gray]{0}
  \textbf{\textcolor{white}{Go}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{At}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{On}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{For}} \\ \hline
              & 0.0 & Start of route      &   0.0 \\ \hline
  \textbf{R}  & 0.0 & Onto Hudson Terrace &   0.7 \\ \hline
  \textbf{L}  & 0.7 & Onto bike path at Bruce Reynolds Blvd &   0.4 \\ \hline
  \textbf{L}  & 1.0 & Onto River Road. STEEP &   2.4 \\ \hline
  \textbf{BL} & 3.4 & TRO River Road         &   4.7 \\ \hline
  \textbf{R}  & 8.1 & @ Circle, take exit to descend down to Boat Basin & 0.0 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.2 & Make a U-turn. Back up we go! \textbf{Note:} \#1 - Alpine &   0.3 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.3 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.5 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.6 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.7 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.8 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.9 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.0 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.1 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.2 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.3 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.4 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.5 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.6 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.7 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.8 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{PIT} & 9.8 & Alpine PD (Regroup Here) \newline \textbf{Note:} End of \#1 - Alpine \newline \textbf{BREAK COLUMN HERE} &   0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{QL} & 9.9 & Alpine Approach Rd &   0.2 \\ \hline
  \textbf{R}  & 10.1 & Route 9W &   4.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{L}  & 14.2 & Oak Tree Rd $\Rightarrow$ Main St $\Rightarrow$ King's Hwy &   2.2 \\ \hline
  \textbf{BL} & 16.4 & Greenbush Rd $\Rightarrow$ Western Hwy S &   3.0 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 16.5 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 16.6 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 16.7 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 16.8 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 16.9 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.0 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.1 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.2 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.3 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.4 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.5 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.6 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.7 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.8 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.9 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 18.0 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 18.1 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 18.2 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 18.3 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 18.4 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 18.5 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{PIT} & 19.0 & Some Deli Somewhere \newline \textbf{BREAK PAGE/COLUMN HERE} &   0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 19.1 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 19.2 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 19.3 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
\end{xtabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the multi-page table packages are helping here, you can simply force the column widths and break by hand:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=0.25in,right=0.25in,top=0.25in,bottom=0.25in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\newenvironment{zz}
{\par\begin{tabular}{|p{0.25in}|p{0.35in}|p{2.25in}|p{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2.85in-8\tabcolsep-5\arrayrulewidth}|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor[gray]{0}
  \textbf{\textcolor{white}{Go}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{At}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{On}} & \textbf{\textcolor{white}{For}} \\ \hline}
{\end{tabular}\par}


\begin{document}
\twocolumn
\centering

\begin{zz}
              & 0.0 & Start of route      &   0.0 \\ \hline
  \textbf{R}  & 0.0 & Onto Hudson Terrace &   0.7 \\ \hline
  \textbf{L}  & 0.7 & Onto bike path at Bruce Reynolds Blvd &   0.4 \\ \hline
  \textbf{L}  & 1.0 & Onto River Road. STEEP &   2.4 \\ \hline
  \textbf{BL} & 3.4 & TRO River Road         &   4.7 \\ \hline
  \textbf{R}  & 8.1 & @ Circle, take exit to descend down to Boat Basin & 0.0 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.2 & Make a U-turn. Back up we go! \textbf{Note:} \#1 - Alpine &   0.3 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.3 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.5 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.6 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.7 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.8 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 8.9 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.0 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.1 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.2 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.3 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.4 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.5 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.6 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.7 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 9.8 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{PIT} & 9.8 & Alpine PD (Regroup Here) \newline \textbf{Note:} End of \#1 - Alpine \newline \textbf{BREAK COLUMN HERE} &   0.1 \\ \hline
\end{zz}

\begin{zz}
  \textbf{QL} & 9.9 & Alpine Approach Rd &   0.2 \\ \hline
  \textbf{R}  & 10.1 & Route 9W &   4.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{L}  & 14.2 & Oak Tree Rd $\Rightarrow$ Main St $\Rightarrow$ King's Hwy &   2.2 \\ \hline
  \textbf{BL} & 16.4 & Greenbush Rd $\Rightarrow$ Western Hwy S &   3.0 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 16.5 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 16.6 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 16.7 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 16.8 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 16.9 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.0 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.1 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.2 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.3 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.4 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.5 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.6 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.7 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.8 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 17.9 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 18.0 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 18.1 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 18.2 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 18.3 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 18.4 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 18.5 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \rowcolor{yellow} \textbf{PIT} & 19.0 & Some Deli Somewhere \newline \textbf{BREAK PAGE/COLUMN HERE} &   0.1 \\ \hline
\end{zz}

\begin{zz}
  \textbf{S}  & 19.1 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 19.2 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
  \textbf{S}  & 19.3 & Keep going forward (filler filler filler) & 0.1 \\ \hline
\end{zz}
\end{document}
```